# Meteor Export collection to React component

Tags: meteor, reactjs

This Meteor code fails to display the data from the mongo collection  `CarsCol` in the browser.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
// /imports/api/collections.js
export const CarsCol = new Mongo.Collection('carsCol');


// /imports/ui/myList.jsx
import React from 'react';

export const ListItems = ({listItems}) => {    //<---- {listItems} undefined
  if (listItems && listItems.length > 0) {
    return (
      <ol>
        {listItems.map((item) => (
          <li key={item._id}>{item.car}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <p>No cars yet!</p>   //<------------ shows in browser
    );
  }
};


// /client/cars.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { ListItems } from '../imports/ui/myList.jsx';
import { CarsCol } from '../imports/api/collections.js';

const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('carsCol');
  if (sub.ready()) {
    const cars = CarsCol.find().fetch();
    onData(null, {cars});
  }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker(composer) (ListItems);
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very familiar problem. Try to pass reference to collection instead of fetched data via props to the component, like this:

```
// /imports/api/collections.js
export const CarsCol = new Mongo.Collection('carsCol');


// /imports/ui/myList.jsx
import React from 'react';

export const ListItems = ({cars}) => {
  const listItems = cars.find().fetch(); // <- fetching data from a collection received as a prop right here

  if (listItems && listItems.length > 0) {
    return (
      <ol>
        {listItems.map((item) => (
          <li key={item._id}>{item.car}</li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <p>No cars yet!</p>   //<------------ shows in browser
    );
  }
};


// /client/cars.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { ListItems } from '../imports/ui/myList.jsx';
import { CarsCol } from '../imports/api/collections.js';

const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('carsCol');
  if (sub.ready()) {
    onData(null, {
      cars: CarsCol // <- now the "cars" prop is the collection
    });
  }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker(composer) (ListItems);
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

I believe that should work, although I'm having strong feeling that you didn't share 100% of the code involved. But hopefully the idea is clear: when subscription is ready, you pass the collection itself, not the data fetched from it, via props, and then perform fetching within the component itself. This way, you'll also preserve reactivity, e.g. when collection is updated, the component will be updated (rendered).

Comment: I removed all the records from the collection but the browser did not update showing nothing. Why the reactivity is not working in this case?

Comment: That's a good question, I haven't ever seen it not working in a way you describe. I think using [tracker-component](https://github.com/studiointeract/tracker-component) would solve the issue, although it would require significant changes in the code.

Comment: I learned that the react-kompose reactivity is done inside the container, thus inside the function `compose`, how can it respond to changes to the mongo collection the collection fetching is moved to the ui component instead like you suggested in the accepted answer? [https://voice.kadira.io/using-meteor-data-and-react-with-meteor-1-3-13cb0935dedb#.bz29237uj]